# How to resolve Type error on local module?

Tags: typescript

I'm getting this error `Type error: Cannot find module './ProjectSlider' or its corresponding type declarations.`

folder structure:

```
- content
  - homepage
    - ProjectSlider.tsx
    - ProjectsList.tsx
```

import to `ProjectsList/tsx`:

```
const DynamicProjectSlider = dynamic(() =>
  import('./ProjectSlider').then((mod) => mod?.ProjectSlider)
)
```

Comment: Does it make a difference if you include the file extension? Eg `import("./ProjectSlider.tsx")`

Comment: Typescript doesn't like that either